# json_decode: object to associative array

Tags: php, arrays, associative-array, json

How can I convert this horrible piece of code to an associative array? :D

```
<?php
$json = file_get_contents('http://pastebin.com/NLHGMapT');
$track_data = json_decode($json);
?>
<ul>
<?php
    foreach ($track_data as $data)

            $text0 = $data->track[0]->artist->{'#text'};
            $text1 = $data->track[1]->artist->{'#text'};
            $text2 = $data->track[2]->artist->{'#text'};
            $text3 = $data->track[3]->artist->{'#text'};
            $artist0 = $data->track[0]->name;
            $artist1 = $data->track[1]->name;
            $artist2 = $data->track[2]->name;
            $artist3 = $data->track[3]->name;
            $url0 = $data->track[0]->url;
            $url1 = $data->track[1]->url;
            $url2 = $data->track[2]->url;
            $url3 = $data->track[3]->url;
        echo '<li><a href="'; echo $url0; echo '"><span>'; echo $text0; echo '</span> - <span>'; echo $artist0; echo '</span></li></a>';
        echo '<li><a href="'; echo $url1; echo '"><span>'; echo $text1; echo '</span> - <span>'; echo $artist1; echo '</span></li></a>';
        echo '<li><a href="'; echo $url2; echo '"><span>'; echo $text2; echo '</span> - <span>'; echo $artist2; echo '</span></li></a>';
        echo '<li><a href="'; echo $url3; echo '"><span>'; echo $text3; echo '</span> - <span>'; echo $artist3; echo '</span></li></a>';
?>
</ul>
```

Comment: I spot a fairly obvious opportunity to use an inner `for` loop from zero to three.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The [second argument to `json_decode`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php) forces the JSON to unserialize to an associative array if it is truthy (it is falsy by default).

That is, use `json_decode($json, true)`

Comment: @MultiformeIngegno they are not objects anymore, they are associative arrays.  Isn't that what you asked for?

Comment: Ehm, yeah.. so how do I call 'em now? :)

Comment: @MultiformeIngegno the usual array access syntax: `$data['track'][0]['artist']['#text']`

Comment: Oh ok it works. The problem is: I wanted to convert objects to associative arrays because I thought this way I could avoid to repeat for every <li> $data['track'][0], $data['track'][1], $data['track'][2], and so on.. is there a way to have this "automatically"?

Comment: @MultiformeIngegno you can; try `foreach ($data['track']`

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/30771/discussion-between-explosion-pills-and-multiformeingegno)